# GWTBootstrap: Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Button to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gwt

I am trying to use GWT-Bootstrap and the I get the following error when running the project:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Button to com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button
```

My ui.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' xmlns:b="urn:import:org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui">

    <ui:with field='res' type='resources.MyResources' />

    <b:Container fluid="true">
        <b:Row>
            <b:Column size="MD_1">
                <g:HTMLPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.maindiv}">
                    <g:VerticalPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.form}">
                        <g:HorizontalPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.formPart}">
                            <g:TextBox ui:field="matrnrTextBox" addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.nameTextBox}" />
                        </g:HorizontalPanel>
                        <g:HorizontalPanel addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.formPart}">
                            <g:PasswordTextBox ui:field="passwordTextBox"
                                addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.passwordTextBox}" />
                        </g:HorizontalPanel>
                        <b:Button text="Block level button" block="true" ui:field="loginButton" />
                                                <!-- <g:Button text="Login" /> --> <!-- ui:field="loginButton" addStyleNames="{res.loginCss.loginButton}" -->
                    </g:VerticalPanel>
                </g:HTMLPanel>
            </b:Column>
        </b:Row>
    </b:Container>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

It works like this, but when I add the `ui:field` attribute to the `b:Button` element, I get the above mentioned error.

How can I access the b:Button from my Java class? Do I have to do it directly through the DOM using the id of the button?

I am using this version of GWTBootstrap:

```
        <groupId>org.gwtbootstrap3</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtbootstrap3</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2</version>
```

Comment: which Button class are you referencing in your view class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing your ui:field like com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button in your java file.

```
@UiField
com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button loginButton;
```

Should be

```
@UiField
org.gwtbootstrap3.client.ui.Button loginButton;
```

Instead. Check the import section